# How to force specific implementation to implement given interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

Sorry for the title but the problem is hard to explain in simple words. 
Having a class:

```
public abstract class SimpleAssembler
    <DI extends IIdBean, DO extends DomainObject, VO extends VOBase>
    implements Assembler<DI, DO, VO> {...}
```

i would like to force the connection between DO and DI so that DO alsways would have to implement the DI. I was trying to make it work like this:

```
    public abstract class SimpleAssembler
    <DI extends IIdBean, DO extends DomainObject & DI, VO extends VOBase>
    implements Assembler<DI, DO, VO> {...}
```

but this would not compile. Another problem is that I am not an owner of DomainObject class definition so it is impossible for me to change it. I can extend is somehow though.
What can I do to force this relationship?

Comment: What is `IIdBean`? Can there be multiple type for `DI`? Just to answer, that is not possible what you're currently doing, but we need some more details.

Comment: Post the complete error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: @RohitJain IIdbean is an interface: public interface IIdBean<T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable> {...}.

Comment: @JBNizet Complete error from compiler: java: SimpleAssembler.java:13: unexpected type
found   : type parameter DI 
required: class

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with pure Generics due to type erasure... but depending on how much cruft you're willing to write to accomplish your goal, this could be a potential (albeit messy) solution.  Without knowing more specifics, it's hard to say if this will cover all of your use case.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

interface Assembler<DI, DO, VO> {
  /* ??? not given ??? */
  void acceptsBean(DI bean);
  void acceptsDomain(DO domain);
}


interface VOBase {
  /* ??? not given ??? */
}


interface IIdBean<T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable> {
  /* as given */
}


class DomainObject {
  /* third-party class, cannot be altered */
}


abstract class AbstractIdBeanDomainObject
  <T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable, I extends IIdBean<T>> 
  extends DomainObject {

  private final Class<I> interfaceType;

  protected AbstractIdBeanDomainObject(Class<I> beanInterface) {
    super();
    if (beanInterface == null 
          || !beanInterface.isAssignableFrom(this.getClass())) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "This class must implement the specified bean type.");
    }
    interfaceType = beanInterface;
  }

  final I asBean() {
    return interfaceType.cast(this);
  }
}

interface IIntIdBean extends IIdBean<Integer> {
  /* ... */
}

class MyIntIdBean implements IIntIdBean {
  /* ... */
}

class MyIntDomainObject extends AbstractIdBeanDomainObject<Integer, IIntIdBean> {
  MyIntDomainObject() {
    super(IIntIdBean.class);
  }
}

class NotSoSimpleAssembler
  <T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable, 
   DI extends IIdBean<T>,
   DO extends AbstractIdBeanDomainObject<T, DI>,
   VO extends VOBase>
  implements Assembler<DI, DO, VO> {

  @Override
  public void acceptsBean(DI bean) { }

  @Override
  public void acceptsDomain(DO domain) { acceptsBean(domain.asBean()); }
}

public class StackOverflow22555608 {
  public static final void main(String[] args) {

    VOBase base = new VOBase() { /* ??? */ };

    IIntIdBean idBean = new MyIntIdBean();

    AbstractIdBeanDomainObject<Integer, IIntIdBean> domainObj =
      new MyIntDomainObject();

    Assembler<IIntIdBean, AbstractIdBeanDomainObject<Integer, IIntIdBean>, VOBase> asm =
      new NotSoSimpleAssembler<>();
    asm.acceptsBean(idBean);
    asm.acceptsDomain(domainObj);
  }
}
```